# Why graph doesn't find correct path?

Tags: python, graph, path, traversal, edge-list

I've tried to create graph with the help of the following link but when I used find_path method I got incorrect path returned. Link:

http://www.python-course.eu/graphs_python.php

Code:

```
class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self, graph_dict=None):
        """ initializes a graph object
            If no dictionary or None is given, an empty dictionary will be used
        """
        if graph_dict is None:
            graph_dict = {}
        self.__graph_dict = graph_dict

    def find_path(self, start_vertex, end_vertex, path=[]):
        """ find a path from start_vertex to end_vertex
            in graph """
        graph = self.__graph_dict
        path = path + [start_vertex]
        if start_vertex == end_vertex:
            return path
        if start_vertex not in graph:
            return None
        for vertex in graph[start_vertex]:
            if vertex not in path:
                extended_path = self.find_path(vertex,
                                               end_vertex,
                                               path)
                if extended_path:
                    return extended_path
        return None

g = {"a": ["c", "d"],
     "b": ["a", "c"],
     "c": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
     "d": ["c", "e"],
     "e": ["c", "f"],
     "f": ["c"]
     }

graph = Graph(g)

"""
graph:

a<----b         <-- one way
|\   /          --- two way
| \ /
|  c <-- f
| / \    ^
v/   \   |
d---->e--/

"""
print graph.find_path("b", "f")

Output: ['b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
Should be: ['b', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

What is wrong with find_path method in Graph class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is finding the path by following the first node in each node's adjacency list that does not already belong in the graph. It starts at `'b'` and then goes to the first node in the adjacency list (`['a', 'c']`) node `'a'`. Then it goes from `'a'` to `'c'`. Once it is at `'c'`, it sees that `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'` are already in the path so it goes to `'d'`. If you changed the order of your adjacency list in the graph to this, it will print out the order your looking for:

```
g = {"a": ["d", "c"],
     "b": ["a", "c"],
     "c": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
     "d": ["e", "c"],
     "e": ["f", "c"],
     "f": ["c"]
     }
```

Alternatively, you can implement a shortest path algorithm such as [Djikstra's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) to find the shortest path through a graph.

Answer (score 1):

You programmed this to find *any* acyclic path, and return the first one it finds.  The path it found is perfectly reasonable; it's simply not the least number of steps.

To find the shortest path, you need to implement either a breadth-first search, or a depth-first search with memoization (keep track of the best known path to each node).  Dijkstra's algorithm is good for the shortest path.